# Why does a div tag break markdown in github-pages

Tags: html, jekyll, github-pages

Using jekyll w/ github-pages

I had this in a index.md:

```
<div class="grey-box">
  GET /projects/<span class="variable project_id">{Project ID}</span>/codes/<span class="variable code_id">{Code ID}</span>/download
</div>
```

and it was breaking markdown when compiling so I changed the div to a span like so:

```
<span class="grey-box">
  GET /projects/<span class="variable project_id">{Project ID}</span>/codes/<span class="variable code_id">{Code ID}</span>/download
</span>
```

CSS:

```
.grey-box {
   background: #EEE;
   padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

Now everything is gravy. Any ideas why the div was causing this error?

Comment: I'm experiencing this error also! can you add the css stylings for grey-box in this example?

Comment: I haven't been able to reproduce the error, but perhaps this has something to do with [how Markdown treats block-level HTML vs span-level HTML](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#html)?

Comment: Which Markdown renderer are you using? Please clarify. This is what Jekyll uses to parse your Markdown.

Comment: The default. I believe it is maruku

Comment: What are on the lines immediately preceding and following the div element? Were there blank lines, or Markdown or other HTML content?

Comment: Don't remember, ended up fencing it and that smoothed things out.

Answer (score 4):

Markdown doesn't parse within block-level HTML elements, of which `<div>` is one.

From [the documentation](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#html):

> Note that Markdown formatting syntax is not processed within block-level HTML tags. E.g., you can’t use Markdown-style *emphasis* inside an HTML block.

This isn't just the case with GitHub Pages, but with the vast majority of Markdown parsers.